# Batch file to edit input file for a program

Tags: loops, batch-file, editing

I want to make a batch file that replaces two lines of another file. I want to do this with a loop that replaces line 67 with i in (text1, text2, text3) and line 68 with j in (num1, num2, num2).

Below is the code for one iteration. I would like to change:

```
set "Replacementiso=SourceTermName = ac-225"
```

with an indexed element in i and

```
set "Replacementsource=SourceTerm = 332"
```

with an indexed element in j.

I would also like to rename the output file with elements in i such that

```
ren file.txt ac-225.txt
```

changes with each iteration.

This is the code:

```
@echo off &setlocal


set "file=file.txt"
set /a isoLine#ToSearch=67
set /a sourceLine#ToSearch=68
set "Replacementiso=SourceTermName = ac-225"
set "Replacementsource=SourceTerm = 332"

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
SET "Line=%%b"
IF %%a equ %isoLine#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacementiso%"
IF %%a equ %sourceLine#ToSearch% SET "Line=%Replacementsource%"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO(!Line!
ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"

ren file.txt ac-225.txt
```

Comment: OK, so what have you tried so far, and do you have a specific question?

Comment: I've edited the post.